# How do I make these table cells sortable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

How do I make these table cells sortable without having the cells pour over the fixed width tbody container?  When I move a cell into a row above or below, the cell in the 3rd column will pour over the container and not go down into the column below or above.....here is my code...

**jQuery**

```
$document.ready(function(){
    $(function() {
        $( "#sortable_grid" ).sortable({
            items: 'td'
            //helper: "clone"
        });

        $( "#sortable_grid" ).disableSelection();
    });
});
```

**CSS**

```
#sortable_grid { 
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  width: 450px;
}
#sortable_grid td {
  margin: 3px 3px 3px 0;
  padding: 1px;
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 90px;
  font-size: 4em;
  text-align: center;
}

.ui-state-default{
  width:100px;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<table id="sortable" border="1" width="300">
<tbody id="sortable_grid">
    <tr width="300">
        <td width="100" class="ui-state-default">1</td>
        <td width="100" class="ui-state-default">2</td>
        <td width="100" class="ui-state-default">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100" class="ui-state-default">4</td>
        <td width="100" class="ui-state-default">5</td>
        <td width="100" class="ui-state-default">6</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="100" class="ui-state-default">7</td>
        <td width="100" class="ui-state-default">8</td>
        <td width="100" class="ui-state-default">9</td>
    </tr>   
    <tr>    
        <td width="100" class="ui-state-default">10</td>
        <td width="100" class="ui-state-default">11</td>
        <td width="100" class="ui-state-default">12</td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

it's a css probleme: the margin cell, the padding, the border table take place in your 300 px div, so your 3 100 px td haven't enought space.

you should use

```
 #sortable_grid td {
...
  width: 91px;
...
}
```

instead of

```
width: 100px;
```

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a direct answer regarding your code, but perhaps you might have more luck using [List JS](http://www.listjs.com/).